# bPopup Re-Centre/How to run JS/jQuery function

Tags: jquery, popup, bpopup

I don't know if anyone is familiar with bPopup but here goes nothing.

I have an AJAX request that is ran, and on success it loads new content into the popup and thus changes the size, how would I re-center the div correctly after this?

[Here is the bPopup code](https://github.com/dinbror/bpopup/blob/master/jquery.bpopup.js)

I have tried running the re-center function however I get the error "Uncaught ReferenceError: bPopup is not defined "
when trying to run the function like this:

```
bPopup.recenter();
```

Any ideas?

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I had a similar situation. The content of my popup changed after loading ajax, but the size of the open popup remained the same.

I suggest that you close the popup, clear the contents of the popup div, and reopen it immediately after. It creates a nice effect, and the new popup is now resized to fit the new content.

Example:

```
$('#buttonToPopup').bind('click', function(e) {  
    $('#popupDIV').bPopup().close();
    $('#popupDIV').empty();  // clear the previous contents of the popup
    $('#popupDIV').bPopup({
       loadUrl: myNewURL     // this is the new ajax content
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Trigger a `$(window).resize()` event.

`recenter()` is private in bPopup. You could call `bPopup().reposition()` to align the popup, but if the user scrolls the page, the popup will be misaligned again. Only triggering a `$(window).resize()` event worked for me:

```
$('#my-button').click(function() {
    // show the popup
    var myPopup = $('#my-popup');
    myPopup.bPopup();
    // load new content
    $.get(myUrl).done(function(data) {
      myPopup.html(data);
      // trigger "window resized"
      $(window).resize();
      // this will not work if the user scrolls the page
      /* myPopup.bPopup().reposition(); */
    });
});
```